# Are there other languages, besides Latin, where a gender of a noun is determined by its genitive case ending?

Tags: cases

Are there other languages, besides Latin, where a gender of a noun is determined by its genitive case ending?

Comment: The gender of a Latin noun is not determined by the genitive case ending. *nauta, nautae* is masculine while *victima, victimae* is feminine. *ratio, rationis* is feminine while *leo, leonis* is masculine.

Comment: As Sumelic says, this isn't actually true in Latin.

Comment: In Latin (and perhaps in other languages), there is a tradition of choosing the genitive case form as part of the citation form for a noun. This doesn't have anything to do with the function of genitive case, just with the facts that almost every noun has such a case form, and that the stem for the genitive was usually the one that appeared on most other case forms -- unlike the nominative singular, which frequently diverged from the genitive stem. Many consonant clusters were lost in the nominative: _mens, mentis; cor, cordis; honos, honoris;_ etc.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of a "genitive case ending" isn't particularly universal; it shows up mostly in Indo-European languages. And no IE language I know of (including Latin) actually shows gender specifically with the genitive ending.

But if you relax your requirements a bit, many Eastern Bantu languages mark gender on the genitive particle. For example, in Swahili:

- *mama **w**a mtoto* "the child's mother", gender #1 (individual people)
- *miti **my**a mtoto* "the child's trees", gender #4 (groups of plants and things that extend)
- *kitabu **ch**a mtoto* "the child's book", gender #7 (artifacts created by humans and small versions of things)

Note that, unlike in IE languages, the genitive marker agrees with the thing being possessed rather than with the possessor.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the grammar of Swahili, but if this is a separate word, it seems like it's an example of a possessive marker agreeing in gender with the head of the surrounding noun phrase (the possessed word is the head), which shows up in Indo-European languages as well: Latin *pater meus* "my-M father" vs. *mater mea* "my-F mother" or French *son père* "his/her-M father" vs. *sa mère* "his/her-F mother". The difference is just that Latin and French don't use this kind of strategy when the possessor is non-pronominal.

Answer (score 0):

For German, it can be said that nouns that have *-(e)s* in the genitive (singular) are not feminine, i.e. they are masculine or neuter. Feminine nouns have no case endings in the singular. Also, neuter nouns have *-(e)s* in the genitive*, whereas masculine nouns have one of *-(e)s*, *-(e)n*, *-(e)ns* (*Mann**es**, Junge**n**, Name**ns***).

However, names have *-(e)s* even if feminine in those contexts where names have an ending (*Maria**s** Stimme, die Stimme Maria**s*** vs. *die Stimme unserer lieben Maria*).

<sub>* One exception: the neuter noun *Herz* has *-ens* in the genitive.</sub>

So the following relationships hold:

1. feminine ↔ no case ending
2. neuter → *-(e)s*
3. *-(e)n* or *-(e)ns* → masculine
4. *-(e)s* → masculine or neuter

Cases 1 and 3 are those where it can be said that the case ending determines the gender.